# Help Refreshing Yahoo's OAuth Access Token in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth, yahoo, access-token

I'm at the point of involuntary hair loss while trying to refresh the Yahoo OAuth access token in Ruby.

Using the OmniAuth and OAuth gems, I'm able to get an access token from Yahoo, however it expires in one hour.

I'm following the Yahoo instructions to [refresh an expired token](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-refreshaccesstoken.html), and am consistently returned a 401.

If someone could show me how to refresh the access token using the OAuth gem, I'd be **greatly** appreciative.

Comment: You can also look at the WWW-authenticate response-header sent from Yahoo to see more information about why a 401 response was returned. It will say something like "oauth_problem=timestamp_refused" or "oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_timestamp".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you are saving your oauth_session_handle parameter from your original `get_access_token` call.

Then, when you are looking to refresh the access_token do something like this:

```
request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.new(consumer, 
                                        config["ACCESS_TOKEN"],             
                                        config["ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"])
token = OAuth::Token.new(config["ACCESS_TOKEN"],
                         config["ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"])
@access_token = request_token.get_access_token(
                         :oauth_session_handle => config["SESSION_HANDLE"],
                         :token => token)
```

... where ...

```
config["ACCESS_TOKEN"] is your old access token
config["ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"] is your old secret
config["SESSION_HANDLE"] is your oauth_session_handle
consumer is your OAuth::Consumer.new reference
```

I store the config variable in a yaml file and then load it on startup.

Remember to store the `@access_token` for next time.

I adapted this from an answer at [YDN OAuth Forum](http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=7212&hl=ruby%20refresh%20token).

Comment: SESSION_HANDLE is necessary.In my code, I missed it, so also get "token_rejected"

Answer (score 1):

Note: oauth_session_handle is returned as a param by the call to get_access_token:

```
access_token         = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => oauth_verifier)  
oauth_session_handle = access_token.params['oauth_session_handle']
```

This was less than obvious from looking at the [oauth-ruby/oauth](https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby) code